# query not executing when some input is given to it via 2 combo boxes and a text field because it work without the "where" thing

Tags: netbeans

```
 String query="select book_code, book_name, student_name, class, roll_no, issue_date, return_date from lib where" + s1 + "" + s2 + "" + s3 + ";" ; 

 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

This is the code where s1,s2 are combo boxes from which the search field and operator is being selected and s3 is the search criteria. 
Where am I wrong?

Comment: First thing, this is not a preferred way of doing database programming. 

Print the query before executing to see the actual query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using string you have to include that in single quotes.

> String query="select book_code, book_name, student_name, class, roll_no, issue_date, return_date from lib where " + s1 + "" + s2 + "'" + s3 + "'";

So use the query in if condition according to the type that you choose.

Comment: sir when i checked the code using system.out.print.ln method i got output. ie. the first line of the code given above i was getting the output but when i did the same after the execute query statement i got no output so does it means that there is an error in the execution line???

Comment: i am giving the "book_code" and "=" in s1 and s2 using the getSelectedItem() method

Comment: 117 normal getText() method

Comment: What do u use in table varchar or int type?

Comment: while(rs.next()){
model.addRow(new Object[] {rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7) }); this is the code after the given above code pls hlp!!!

Comment: Replace your query like i have edited. If still not working post your full code.

Comment: thank u bro thanks a lot it worked!!!!!!!!! cheers but will u let me know that where was i actually going wrong?? sorry for the late reply.

Comment: You just had passed the string as such but it need to be converted to integer as it is stored as integer in the table. got it.

Comment: buddy it worked for the book code thing but it didn't work for the student name and class thing because both of them are in varchar type now what do i do??

Comment: You might have missed single quotes for the string. I ll edit my answer.

Comment: u were absolutely right but very sorry to ask that using single quotes helped us how???

Comment: Its mysql sytax to include single quotes when you compare string.Anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake might be that you are missing a space when concatenating your query like this.

```
where" + s1 + "" + s2 + "" + s3 + ";"
```

(there is no space after the where keyword)